# DataflowPipelineOptions: set runner explicitly using .setRunner after arg parsing

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In dataflow SDK 2.4.0, I used to be able to run:

```
 PipelineOptionsFactory.register(MyPipelineOptions.class);
 MyPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create().as(MyPipelineOptions.class);
 options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
```

However, in Apache Beam SDK 2.9.0, I need to set the runner in the args using `--runner=DataflowRunner`, because otherwise it fails on `create()` (second line). Is this desired behaviour or is there still a way to set the runner using `setRunner` after reading other options from args?

Maven dependencies used:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: setRunner should still work with SDK 2.9.0 like it did with 2.4.0. In fact, I just tested it and it works for me. Can you share an MCVE so we can see what causes this to you?

Comment: Running the above code (even with `MyPipelineOptions` an empty interface extending `DataflowPipelineOptions`) makes the code fail on line 2 (where I create the options instance). The code at line 3 can't get executed before line 2, so the only option is to specify it via command args. The error I get: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Runner was specified and the DirectRunner was not found on the classpath.`

Comment: Can you try adding beam-runners-direct-java to your dependencies as well? Even if you don't use the direct runner, it seems that it needs to be in the classpath

Comment: Added the dependency and it works now, thanks!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer in case that can help somebody else then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, if no runner is specified when the options object is created, it defaults to  DirectRunner. So, even if setRunner is later used to define another runner, just to be able to create the options object with no runner specified, DirectRunner needs to be in the classpath.

To make it work you can just add the dependency to have DirectRunner in your classpath

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```